# What does const lambda mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, constants

```
#include <iostream>
int foo(int i)
{
    const auto a = [&i](){ i = 7; };
    a();
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(42) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles( `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic main.cpp` ) and prints `7`. Which is surprising to me, because by declaring `a` to be a constant object, I would have expected `i` to be referenced as `const int&`. It clearly isn't, why?

Comment: Which part of your code captures `j` by const ref? I don't understand the problem. You made a function to take `i`, ignore its value, make it 7, square it, then return the result (49) ... which is exactly what happened! All you're doing with `j` is briefly storing 49 in a named variable before returning it. Can you clarify your intention please.

Comment: Now you don't have a variable named `j` at all. All you're doing with this altered code is setting `i` to 7, returning 49 then discarding that 49 value.

Comment: Because you captured by non-const ref. That's just like asking why on can modify stuff though a `int *const`.

Comment: I dont understand your question like @LightnessRacesinOrbit stated.

Comment: I wonder what is the effect of the `const` specifier in front of the lambda.

Comment: @Vorac: Nothing... it means you wouldn't be able to alter `a`, or its members, but you're not trying to do that here anyway. Were you expecting it to magically change the internal `int&` to a `const int&`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can't alter `a` anyhow, because it is of unique type. Concerning its members: why is `&i` not its member and hence `const &i`?

Comment: @Slayther: No, the result of the lambda is not assigned to anything. The lambda itself is stored in `a` but that's an initialisation, not an assignment.

Comment: @Vorac: Sorry, but without knowing how you arrived at this conclusion I cannot correct your misunderstanding, other than to say "the compiler is right" (or by explaining every detail of how lambdas work in the hopes of stumbling upon the part you got wrong... which I won't do!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tried to clarify the question by editing it. What other context can I give, so that the question is clear?

Comment: It's better now; thanks. As you can see, the edit has led to some great answers. :) +1

Comment: I'm a bit late to this party, but indeed this is a nice use case for C++ Insights: https://cppinsights.io/s/fe317135

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lambdas are just like non-lambdas, except their implementation details are hidden. Therefore, it may be easier to explain using a non-lambda functor:

```
#include <iostream>
int foo(int i)
{
    struct F {
      int &i;
      int operator()() const { i = 7; return i * i; }
    };
    const F a {i};
    a();
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(42) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`F` has a `int &` reference member `i`. `const F` cannot have its instance data modified, but a modification to `i` isn't a modification to its instance data. A modification to its instance data would be re-binding `i` to another object (which isn't allowed anyway).

Answer (score 15):

```
[&i](){ i = 7; return i * i; }
```

is mainly equivalent to

```
class Lambda
{
public:
    Lambda(int& arg_i) : i(arg_i) {}

    auto operator() () const { i = 7; return i * i;}
private:
    int& i;
};
```

And so then you have:

```
const Lambda a(i);
a();
```

And the `const Lambda` won't *promote* its member to `const int& i;` but `int& const i;` which is equivalent to `int& i;`.

Answer (score 8):

When you capure `i` it is captured as the type it is.

So internally it has a `int&`. A const before the variable declaration of the closure does not change anything for the lambda.

You have 2 options to solve this:

```
const int i = 5;
auto b = [&i]() { i++; }; //error on i++
```

This way a `const int&` will be captured.

If you cannot change `i` for some reasons you can do this in c++14

```
int i = 5;
auto b = [i = static_cast<const int&>(i)]() { i++; }; //error on i++
```

This casts the `int&` to a `const int&` and will be stored as such in the lambda. Though this is way more verbose as you can see.

Comment: If he doesn't want to change `i` it might be better to take it by copy.

Comment: @krzaq yeah but this would be useful for cases where you have bigger objects you don't want to copy. In case of `int` this is kind of not needed.

Answer (score 2):

**In the code you gave:**

```
int foo(int i)
{
    const auto a = [&i](){ i = 7; return i * i; };
    a();
    return i;
}
```

You are not assigning after you initialized your constant lambda function. Therefore, `const` doesn't mean much in this context.

Comment: I didn't, but your answer doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: @krzaq it states in my answer : The OP Initialized the constant lambda at first. And then he didn't assign that lambda a different value , there the `const` modifier doesn't play a big role here.. What don't you understand about that?

Comment: Me neither. 
`@Vorac: Nothing... it means you wouldn't be able to alter a, or its members, but you're not trying to do that here anyway. Were you expecting it to magically change the internal int& to a const int&? – Lightness Races in Orbit 9 mins ago` Your answer addresses the first point, while my struggle is with the second. I edited the question in an attempt to clear this up.

Comment: @Vorac what dont you get.. please state.

Comment: I downvoted it because it doesn't say anything of value.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok i guess you dont consider answering the question anything of value.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the question is why you're allowed to mutate `i` even though `a` is `const` and presumably contains a reference to `i` as a member.

The answer is that it's for the same reason that you're allowed to do this on any object - assigning to `i` doesn't modify the lambda instance, it modifies an object it refers to.

Example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int& y) : x(y) {} 
    void foo(int a) const { x = a; } // But it's const?!
private:
    int& x;
};

int main()
{
    int e = 0;
    const A a(e);
    a.foo(99);
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles, and prints "99", because `foo` isn't modifying a member of `a`, it's modifying `e`.
(This is slightly confusing, but it helps to think about which *objects* are being modified and disregard how they're named.)

This "const, but not really" nature of `const` is a very common source of confusion and annoyance.

This is exactly how pointers behave, where it's more obviously not wrong:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int* y) : x(y) {} 
    void foo(int a) const { *x = a; } // Doesn't modify x, only *x (which isn't const).
private:
    int* x;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have declared as `const` it isn't the context of your anonymous function or lambda exspression and its parameters, but only the reference at that lambda expression: `const auto a`.

Therefore, you cannot change the value of your lambda expr reference `a` because it is const, but its parameter passed by reference, `&i`, can be changed within the context of lambda expression.

Comment: `a` is not a reference.

Comment: I haven't gone in language details level.. I thought that was sufficient give an abstract indication of the role of the variable assigned with lambda expression address, and that is: a "reference" to a lambda expression or an anonymous function...

Comment: It is not a reference.